# Можно ли реализовать редирект раздела на php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Хочу реализовать аналог такого редиректа:

`RewriteRule ^category-old/(.*)$ /category-new/$1 [R=301,L]`.

Hо на PHP. Как это сделать?

Comment: `header('location: /category-new/....')`

Comment: teran, не понял, что за точки. Как из URI взять все после category-old/ и вставить после category-new/

Answer (score 0):

```php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode('?', $url);
$url = $url[0];
$urlMatch = preg_match('/\/category-old\//', $url, $matches);
if ($urlMatch > 0) {
    $urlNew = str_replace('/category-old/', '', $url);
    header('location: /category-new/$urlNew');
}
```

(я новичок, приношу извинения, если есть ошибки)

Comment: вы проверяете просто вхождение `category-old`, само регулярное выражение должно оставаться тем же каикм и было `/^category-old\/(.*)` в итоге в `$matches[1]` вы получите нужное соответствие, и просто дальше сделать редирект в `/category-new/{$matches[1]}`